# FileNotFoundException - no space left on device

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

On our production Linux box, we're getting a `FileNotFoundException` which an additional message of "no space left on device".

I read here and there on the web, that the problem could be related to the count of `inodes` but seems that's not the problem here. Our system admins are confirming that we have enough `inodes`.

What else could it be?! I've been digging into this for 2 days now.

I can provide any additional information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Here is the exact stack trace.

```
13 Nov 2014 10:09:32 ERROR error:113 - Failed to move file: /wr/data/import/xml/YC00210097_ba7b688c-6b46-11e4-b8e8-07cc96f6b24f_1415891227642.xml.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /wr/data/import/processeddir/YC00210097_ba7b688c-6b46-11e4-b8e8-07cc96f6b24f_1415891227642_2014_11_13_10_09_32_241.xml (No space left on device)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:671)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:607)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:1818)
    at com.yellowbook.util.YBFileIterator.finished(YBFileIterator.java:105)
    at com.yellowbook.diadexchange.exchangejob.ImportJob.execute(ImportJob.java:279)
    at com.yellowbook.scheduling.diadexchange.JobExchangeScheduler.executeImportJob(JobExchangeScheduler.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:311)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
```

Comment: Does the device have enough space left?

Comment: you can have plenty of inodes available and STILL have no space, e.g.  a 100gig drive with a single 100gig file will have tons of inodes, and no space at all.

Comment: @Sizik Yes, that's the first thing the sys admins checked: we have enough disk space and enough inodes, they say.

Comment: This can be thrown due to an access issue for that file.

Comment: @SimplyCraig It's not permissions too. The file can be copied/moved there as far as permissions are concerned.

Comment: What's the filesystem type ext3/4 etc? How many files are currently in the destination directory. Are you absolutely certain sysadmins are checking the right box?

Comment: Have you told your sysadmins the exact location of the file you're attempting to access? They might be checking disk space for the wrong disk partition, or you might be trying to access something on a read-only partition.

Comment: Make sure you aren't accidentally putting a space after the file name, I have seen that before as well.

Comment: @robinj They know all this. They have been managing this Linux box for years.

Comment: @SimplyCraig That's not the problem too (as the error is not always there), it's not persistent.

Comment: @peter.petrov Are you sure that there are no temporary spikes in the disk space/inodes used? I see that the file is in directory `processeddir` so I suppose this might be the case. Perhaps you can check the number of files/used space in directory when catching the exception.

Comment: @user3584460 We'll look into that, thanks. I have our sys admin following this thread.

Comment: @user3584460 The file is in fact in another folder `xml`. The app tries moving it to `processeddir` and it fails even though there's enough disk space on that mount where `processeddir` is.

Comment: @peter.petrov Have you seen [this thread](http://serverfault.com/a/384554)? Also, is there any quota setup for the filesystem (although quota is not a popular choice for ext4 as I know)? I guess that also you can try to run some system utilities like `df` from your application to find at least if the problem are the inodes or the free space.

Comment: @user3584460 Thanks, I think that helped. Seems the count of the files in `processeddir` was the problem. I will keep monitoring this app for a few more days though just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of the files in `processeddir` was the problem. So we were getting this (seemingly confusing) `FileNotFoundException` because there were too many files in the target directory. After we archived a big subset of these files into a compressed (but single) file, the exception disappeared.